# Insert item in DB with two columns using Scala and Play Framework

Tags: scala, anorm, playframework-2.4

I've followed [this application tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList). Basically, in this app they create a todo item. I've replicated the model to a survey application, and I want to create a question that contains both question text and question type (binary, text entry etc). I get various degrees of errors regarding my question form formatting, etc but the main problem seems to be in the `newQuestion` action on

```
questionForm.bindFromRequest.fold(errors=> ..., question=> ...)
```

My code is formatted as follows:

QuestionController.scala:

```
def questions = Action {
  Ok(views.html.question(Question.all(), questionForm))
}

def newQuestion = Action { implicit request =>
  questionForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest(views.html.question(Question.all(), errors)),
      question => {     
        Question.create(question)
        Redirect(routes.QuestionController.questions)      
    }
  )
}

def deleteQuestion(id: Long) = Action {
  Question.delete(id)
  Redirect(routes.QuestionController.questions)
}

val questionForm = Form(
  "questiontext" -> nonEmptyText    
)
```

CaseClass/companion object Question.scala:

```
case class Question (id:Long, questionText:String, questionType:String)

object Question {
  val question = {
    get[Long]("id") ~
      get[String]("questiontext") ~
      get[String]("questiontype") map {
      case id~questiontext~questiontype => Question(id, questiontext,questiontype)
    }
  }

  def all(): List[Question] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("select * from questions").as(question *)
  }

  def create(text:String) {
    DB.withConnection {
      implicit c =>
        SQL("insert into questions(questiontext) values ({text})").on(
          'text -> text
        //'quesType -> qType
        ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }

  def delete(id:Long) {
    DB.withConnection{ implicit c =>
        SQL("delete from questions where id = {id}").on(
          'id -> id
        ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
}
```

I essentially want to run create with two parameters as such:

```
def create(text:String,qType:String) {
  DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("insert into questions(questiontext,questiontype) values ({text},{quesType})").on(
      'text -> text,
      'quesType -> qType
    ).executeUpdate()
  }
}
```

But I'm unsure how to handle this in the `bindFromRequest.fold` as mentioned previously.

- I tried editing the `questionForm` to use a mapping and using `(Question.apply)(Question.unapply)` as well as just a tuple and the `questiontext -> nonEmptyText` and `questionType -> nonEmptyText` contained in that tuple with no luck.
- I edited the `scala.html` file to contain the right type of value accordingly with still no luck.
- I can get it to save with one column but it crashes because I defined the `questionType` to be a required field in pgsql and the get fails on the `~get questionType from *` after appending without a question type.

UPDATE:

I've edited it to try and emulate the code here: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.1/ScalaForms

So now, I am using the following code:

```
  def questions = Action {
    Ok(views.html.question(Question.all(), questionForm))
  }


  def newQuestion = Action { implicit request =>
    logger.error(s"wtf")
    questionForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => {BadRequest(views.html.question(Question.all(), errors))
      },
      question => {
            Question.create(question:Question)
            Redirect(routes.QuestionController.questions).flashing("success"->"Question saved successfully!")
      }
    )
  }

  def deleteQuestion(id: Long) = Action {
    Question.delete(id)
    Redirect(routes.QuestionController.questions)
  }

  val questionForm:Form[Question]=Form(mapping(
  "id" -> longNumber,
  "versionid" -> longNumber,
    "questiontext" -> nonEmptyText,
  "questiontype" -> nonEmptyText)(Question.apply)(Question.unapply)

  )
```

I've updated my question.scala.html file to take `@(questions: List[Question], questionForm: Form[(Question)])` as inputs.

when i hit submit, I keep getting the Log message of :wtf

Following the example i most recently linked, I am not understanding why it does not go to the case of `question` and continue to create the question in the database. I updated my database create function as the following as well:

```
  def create(question:Question) {
    DB.withConnection {
      implicit c =>
        SQL("insert into questions(questiontext,questiontype,versionid) values ({text},{quesType},{versId})").on(
          'text -> question.questionText,
        'quesType -> question.questionType,
        'versId -> 1.toLong
        ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the help thus far, I hope I can figure out what I am doing wrong shortly.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I'm unable to provide two arguments properly to Question.create in the bindFromRequest.fold

Comment: The `bindFromRequest` is to bind [data from request to some data types](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/ScalaForms) which will be then process, and result in a new view. You can bind your request to a tuple `(String, String)` and then call the `create` function with such extract data.

Comment: yeah i thought i tried that, but it did finally work. i think i will be able to bind it to a mapping as well, the errors told me to use pattern matching to take in a 2-tuple like this:
def newQuestion = Action { implicit request =>
    questionForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.question(Question.all(), errors)),
      {case (questiontext,questiontype) => {
            Question.create(questiontext,questiontype)
            Redirect(routes.QuestionController.questions)
        }
      }
    )
  }